# JasperReports: Changing a Pattern Value based on a Field

Tags: jasper-reports, report

I have a field that contains the type of data coming in on the detail fields. It is either an Integer or an Currency value. [An Integer is not a Currency value] The field that is outputing the value is typed as a double, and the text field is currently ####.##.

Is there any way that the pattern can change based on a field value [the field value that makes this either or is a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Jasper report can access all classes available on the classpath. Create a static method which will accept an Object as an argument, check if it is Currency or Integer and return well formatted String value. Import the class in the report and invoke the formatting method from the field.

Answer (score 2):

Now, at least in version 4.7.1, there is an "Patern Expr."

ex:

`$F{Field}.abs().compareTo( new BigDecimal(1) ) < 0 ? "0.0#####E0#" : "#,##0.00"`